# which one must be used with "lately" in THIS question?

Tags: grammar, present-perfect

I saw this test ==> **Why ....... any good news lately?**

and doubted between these two choices:

1. hasn't there been
2. there hasn't been

which one must be used here, with lately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query about ***lately*** is odd, since both your sentences have the same tense, present perfect.

The correct version is

> Why ***hasn't there been*** any good news lately?

not because it contains the word *lately*, but because it is a question, and in questions, [subject-auxiliary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93auxiliary_inversion#In_questions) inversion is required.

What may have confused you is the *dummy subject* ***there***:

> Sometimes we need to use a ‘dummy’ or ‘empty’ or ‘artificial’ subject
> when there is no subject attached to the verb, and where the real
> subject is somewhere else in the clause. ***It*** and ***there*** are the two
> dummy subjects used in English:
>
> - ***There** are* five Dutch people in our village. (The real subject is the Dutch people – they are in the village.) ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/dummy-subjects))

So the affirmative version of your sentence is:

> ***There*** ***hasn't*** been any good news lately.

In your question which begins with ***why***, the subject *there* must be placed after the auxiliary *hasn't*.